# Vacuum tube electric symbols

Tags: symbols, packages

Is there a package with the electric symbols for vacuum tubes, like triodes, pentodes etc?

Comment: I do not know, whether the wanted symbols are in there, but take a look on `circuitikz`.

Comment: @Speravir: I have not seen them in the version 0.3.0.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke A feature request for the OP? :-)

Comment: @Speravir :-) If  vacuum tubes are not creatures from fairy tales for the author of `circuitikz`.[Offtopic, in Polish, but close to this topic. From Cyberiad by Stanisław Lem]:  ,,Dosyć, że Triody znikł, ledwo "Awruk!!" krzyknąć zdołał, słowo ulubione, zawołanie bitewne rodu. Heptody zaś dążył uparcie dalej, ale i jego czekał kres gorzki.''

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Sadly, no online translater works in a understandable way (pl –> de) – well, at least I got a notion. Most funny: No one knows “Awruk”, but I as a German recognize …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, e.g. the `eltex` package: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eltex.

```
\documentclass[bezier]{article}

\input{eltex1}
\input{eltex2}
%\input{eltex3}
\input{eltex4}
%\input{eltex5}
%\input{eltex6}
%\input{eltex7}


\begin{document}

\begin{picture}(0,0)(30,30)
\put(5,5){\triode{a}{b}}
\put(20,5){\pentode{a}{b}{c}}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Speravir: OK, but I don't know, how to put the resulting PDF.